# How to mount SMB share via fstab? (Works with manual mount command.)

Tags: mount, samba, fstab

The following mount command works on my system:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.20/share -o user=guest,password=0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8 /mnt/mit
```

However, adding the equivalent fstab entry...

```
//192.168.0.20/share  /mnt/mit  cifs  user=guest,password=0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

causes `mount -av` to hang:

```
$ sudo mount -av
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.0.20,unc=\\192.168.0.20\share,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,user=,pass=********
```

The command never finishes.
What am I doing wrong?

More details:

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- `cifs-utils` is installed on the system.
- When manually mounting via `sudo mount -t ...`, the corresponding line in
  `/etc/mtab`  is:

  ```
  //192.168.0.20/share /mnt/mit cifs rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=guest,domain=MIT,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.0.20,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,actimeo=1 0 0
  ```

  (Copying this into fstab leads to the same debug output and the same hanging.)

Comment: I think it is already mounted, unless you specify an option `noauto` in fstab.

Comment: No, `mount -av` hangs while the share is being mounted. I get a `already mounted` debug msg when manually mounting before running `mount -av`.

Comment: Is the share directory on the remote system protected with a password?

Comment: I use that kind of line in fstab without problem.  The major difference is that I just specify `username=guest`, without password.defined.  So I would recommend to try that way, stripping all options: `//192.168.0.20/share  /mnt/mit  cifs  username=guest`

Comment: I had already tried that before, but sadly it doesn't work. (Removing only the password or using the stripped-down entry from your last comment.)